# java.io.IOException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, pkcs#11

I'm trying to digitally sign XML documents. For that I have 2 options. There's a library for programmers created by Estonian Certifying Centre and there is a script, that runs a Java code, made by a bank. If using the official (Certifying Centre) library then everything works like a charm with a little bit of tweaking, but when it comes to the bank script then it goes berserk resulting in errors:

```
java.io.IOException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
esteid-pkcs11
        at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Implementation.connect(Native Method)
        at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Implementation.<init>(PKCS11Implementation.java:166)
        at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Connector.connectToPKCS11Module(PKCS11Connector.java:75)
        at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module.getInstance(Module.java:202)
        at client.smartcard.SmartcardHelper.initializePKCS11Module(SmartcardHelper.java:46)
        at client.smartcard.SmartcardHelper.initialize(SmartcardHelper.java:29)
        at client.smartcard.SmartcardHelper.initialize(SmartcardHelper.java:21)
        at client.Signer.main(Signer.java:36)
10:03:31 ERROR - Signing failed: PKCS11 initialization failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: PKCS11 initialization failed
        at client.smartcard.SmartcardHelper.initializePKCS11Module(SmartcardHelper.java:52)
        at client.smartcard.SmartcardHelper.initialize(SmartcardHelper.java:29)
        at client.smartcard.SmartcardHelper.initialize(SmartcardHelper.java:21)
        at client.Signer.main(Signer.java:36)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
esteid-pkcs11
        at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Implementation.connect(Native Method)
        at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Implementation.<init>(PKCS11Implementation.java:166)
        at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Connector.connectToPKCS11Module(PKCS11Connector.java:75)
        at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module.getInstance(Module.java:202)
        at client.smartcard.SmartcardHelper.initializePKCS11Module(SmartcardHelper.java:46)
        ... 3 more
```

`Esteid-pkcs11` file is a country-specific dll-file. I have read lot of responses on google to problems that resulted with the same error, but none of the replies seem to do the trick. I have installed JDK(64-bit) and JRE(32-bit). I thought that maybe the `.dll` file I tried opening is 32-bit and so I changed `JAVA_HOME` path to point to 32-bit JRE, but then it said something like

> cannot load IA 32-bit .dll on a amd 64-bit platform.

So I figured that it isn't a problem with bits. After messing around with environment variables for few hours I figured that it might be a problem with the bank-made script. Can that be the case? If not what else is there that can cause this error?

Edit: Apparently I tried using C-library for signing and it works, but when using Java-library, it gives me an error.

`java.io.IOException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. 
opensc-pkcs11.dll`

I am 100% sure that opensc-pkcs11.dll is a 64-bit dll, but I was wondering if maybe console don't have access to system32 folder. Can that be the case?

Comment: "%1" looks like a missing placeholder in a batch script... Looks like you need to pass an argument to it.

Comment: @echo off
call env.bat
java %JAVA_OPTIONS% client.Signer %*
This is what the batch script looks like.

Comment: When calling the batch script I use something like: "sign.bat signCert=idcard file=test.xml"

Answer (score 6):

The error

Caused by: java.io.IOException: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

is what I got when I tried to use a 32-bit PKCS#11 DLL, via the Sun PKCS#11 Provider, from a 64-bit Java environment.

When I switched to a 64-bit PKCS#11 DLL the error stopped occurring.

I think your 'esteid-pkcs11' file is a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: In my case the problem was 32bit JAVA on a 64bit windows

Answer (score 1):

Maybe opensc-pkcs11.dll contains references to other dlls on the same directory.

I had a similar error with Gemalto (Safenet) crpytoki.dll. The solution was to put the directory containing cryptoki.dll into Windows PATH.